# Getting TypeError: Failed to fetch in Progressive Web Apps

Tags: progressive-web-apps

I am new and trying to resolve this issue  but i am unable to understand where i am doing it wrong and i have tried the solution but i am not getting any solution

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
   console.log("instALL");
   event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('first-app')
      .then(function(cache) {
        cache.addAll([
          './',
          './index.html',
          './src/css/app.css',
          './src/js/app.js'
        ])
      })
   );
    return self.clients.claim();
   });
   console.log("DONE");

    self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    event.respondWith(
     caches.match(event.request)
       .then(function(res) {
         return res;
        })
        );
      });
```

I am unable to use it offline. because of error

Comment: Look at the network panel of the browser's developer tools and see what request is failing.

Comment: abrahan when i load my site first its working fine but when i refresh the same it shows the errors. i have made a sw.js which is unable to fetch.

Comment: Does the Chrome Lighthouse PWA audit give you any errors? Usually, if that does, it also gives you hints on what to fix.